# Will there be any limitations if we upgrade from open source InfluxDB on-premises v1.8 to open source InfluxDB on-premises v2.7.4?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, influxql

I am using opensource 1.8 influxdb version.
I need to upgrade and continue opensource.
I have 140 GB data in 1.8. version.
We need to switch to v2 opensource onpremises quickly. What are the limitations of v2.7.4 using opensource free? We have 140GB of data and millions of measurement points. ***Will we encounter any limitations in terms of data size or number of measurement points if we install v2.7.4 opensource? Will there be any usage and sizing limitations between the open source version and the paid version v2.7.4 ?***

**I asked Bard AI. It told me below :**
The free tier of InfluxDB 2.0 has a data limit of 1 million measurement points and 10 GB of data.
Is this true?
Will there be any usage and sizing limitations between the open source version and the paid version v2.7.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer from Influxdb comunity :**

Believe that’s only true for cloud hosted , if you self host I think the only limits are you hardware (although there may be other factors like your data cardinality)